# VBA Excel How to delete filter blank rows (but not entire row) and shift cells up

Tags: vba, excel

I want to delete only the blank cells (not an entire row) in a very large spreadsheet and want to shift the below cells up.

You can get an idea from the spreadsheet snapshot.

Can someone please help? I am working on very large spreadsheets.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: would you consider non-vba method?

Comment: Yes, I would. I want to get this thing done and preferably as easy as it could be : ). Manually, it is taking ages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use SpecialCells, e.g.

```
Sub x()
On Error Resume Next
Range("C:D").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete shift:=xlUp
'or
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.offset(,2).resize(,2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete shift:=xlUp
On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

The On Error is to avoid an error if there are no blanks.

Comment: I don't know but I am unable to run it as a VBA code as nothing shows when I press ALT + F8.

Comment: Did you include a Sub/End Sub - I didn't post the full code - but you would have had an error.

Comment: Thank you SJR this code worked like a charm. However, I also have blank cells in F,G columns (not showing in the screenshot sorry my bad). Is it possible to apply this code only on C and D columns please.

Comment: Yes, I have amended the code and provided 2 alternatives, the latter of which is probably more efficient (untested).

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank you very very much. You have saved like 15 days of my work. Please keep up the good work. Thanks once again (Y)

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it. This will remove blank cells from every column on your sheet

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub RemoveBlanks()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c

    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        On Error Resume Next
        With rng.Parent
            For Each c In rng
                Range(c, c.Offset(.Cells(.Rows.Count, c.Column).End(xlUp).Row - c.Row, 0)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete shift:=xlUp
            Next c
        End With
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing selected"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: To select the range interactively use a dialog, you ca use `Set ThisRng = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Get Range", Type:=8)`

Comment: Dear Tom, Thank you for reply. I got an error of 'no cells were found' with this code. I forgot to mention I am not expert in excel and am not sure whether I should change some values in your code. Also, I have blank cells in E, F, G, H columns which I don't want to delete or move. Thanks

Comment: @Prasanna You're right you could - after watchme comment I've implemented your suggestion

Comment: @watchme This is due to it not finding any blank cells. Have a look at my update this will take an input from an `InputBox` as suggested by Prasanna

Comment: Dear Tom, Thank you very much for your help. This code is also working but it also removed the blank cells in other columns than C and D. I know I was not clear in my question. But thank you once again